# c# How to get added events?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I am sitting infront of my pc wondering how to get all added events. I just read some articles including [A C# Bedtime Story](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1629/NET-Delegates-A-C-Bedtime-Story) to better understand events and I think that I got the main idea now. But still I couldn't figure out how to get the List of methods/delegates that are executed if an event is fired. Actually in my case it'd be enough if I knew if any method/delegate is assigned to a certain event.
for example: I am using `Gma.UserActivityMonitor` (for keyboard/mouse-hooking)
Now I want to know if the event `HookManager.KeyUp` event is not null.
If it is null a delegate shout be added. In my case this one \/

```
HookManager.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(HookManager_KeyUp);
```

### Edit

example code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;
using Gma.UserActivityMonitor;

namespace EventTest 
{ 
    public partial class Form1 : Form 
    { 
        public Form1() 
        { 
            InitializeComponent();             
            HookManager.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(HookManager_KeyUp);
            Delegate[] a = GetEventSubscribers(button1, "Click");
            label1.Text = a[0].Method.ToString();
        } 
        void HookManager_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
        {         
            /* Do something*/     
        } 
        bool NoEventAttached() 
        { 
            return false; 
        }

        public static Delegate[] GetEventSubscribers(object target, string eventName) 
        { 
            Type t = target.GetType(); 
            var eventInfo = t.GetEvent(eventName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static); 

            do 
            { 
                FieldInfo[] fia = t.GetFields(
                    BindingFlags.Static | 
                    BindingFlags.Instance | 
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic); 

                foreach (FieldInfo fi in fia) 
                { 
                    if (fi.Name == eventName) 
                    { 
                        Delegate d = fi.GetValue(target) as Delegate;                         
                        if (d != null)                         
                            return d.GetInvocationList(); 
                    } 
                    else if (fi.FieldType == typeof(EventHandlerList)) 
                    { 
                        ----> var obj = fi.GetValue(target) as EventHandlerList; 
                        var eventHandlerFieldInfo = obj.GetType().GetField("head", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic); 
                        do 
                        { 
                            var listEntry = eventHandlerFieldInfo.GetValue(obj); 
                            var handler = listEntry.GetType().GetField("handler", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic); 
                            if (handler != null) 
                            { 
                                var subD = handler.GetValue(listEntry) as Delegate; 
                                if (subD.GetType() != eventInfo.EventHandlerType) 
                                { 
                                    eventHandlerFieldInfo = listEntry.GetType().GetField("next", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic); 
                                    obj = listEntry as EventHandlerList; <-----------
                                    continue; 
                                } 
                                if (subD != null) 
                                { 
                                    return subD.GetInvocationList(); 
                                } 
                            } 
                        } 
                        while (eventHandlerFieldInfo != null);                 
                    } 
                } 
                t = t.BaseType; 
            } while (t != null);          
            return new Delegate[] { }; 
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }


    } 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Take note to this console application, and specifically the line calling `GetInvocationList()`. That method returns the list of delegates attached. Each `Delegate` has a `Method` property. Each `Method` property has a `Name`.

### Delegate is Owned by You

```
internal class Program
{
    public event EventHandler CheckInvocationList;

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.CheckInvocationList += new EventHandler(p_CheckInvocationList);
        p.Method1();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" | ", p.CheckInvocationList.GetInvocationList().Select(d => d.Method.Name).ToArray()));
    }

    static void p_CheckInvocationList(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Method1()
    {
        this.CheckInvocationList += new EventHandler(Program_CheckInvocationList);
    }

    void Program_CheckInvocationList(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

### Delegate is NOT Owned by You

Ok, this gets a little messy, but it gets you the answer you want. Even if the internal implementation uses an `EventHandlerList` (which is somewhat common), **but** I cannot gaurantee it would work in absolutely every scenario because there can be so many different internal representations.

However, hopefully this will work for you. As you can see in the example I'm using the `BackgroundWorker` class as my example class for getting the invocation list for a specific event I do not own.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork2);
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" | ", GetEventSubscribers(worker, "DoWork").Select(d => d.Method.Name).ToArray()));
    }

    static void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    static void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    static void worker_DoWork2(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    static void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static Delegate[] GetEventSubscribers(object target, string eventName)
    {
        Type t = target.GetType();
        var eventInfo = t.GetEvent(eventName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

        do
        {
            FieldInfo[] fia = t.GetFields(
                 BindingFlags.Static |
                 BindingFlags.Instance |
                 BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            foreach (FieldInfo fi in fia)
            {
                if (fi.Name == eventName)
                {
                    Delegate d = fi.GetValue(target) as Delegate;
                    if (d != null)
                        return d.GetInvocationList();
                }
                else if (fi.FieldType == typeof(EventHandlerList))
                {
                    dynamic obj = fi.GetValue(target) as EventHandlerList;
                    var eventHandlerFieldInfo = obj.GetType().GetField("head", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                    do
                    {
                        var listEntry = eventHandlerFieldInfo.GetValue(obj);
                        var handler = listEntry.GetType().GetField("handler", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                        if (handler != null)
                        {
                            var subD = handler.GetValue(listEntry) as Delegate;
                            if (subD.GetType() != eventInfo.EventHandlerType)
                            {
                                eventHandlerFieldInfo = listEntry.GetType().GetField("next", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                                obj = listEntry;
                                continue;
                            }
                            if (subD != null)
                            {
                                return subD.GetInvocationList();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    while (eventHandlerFieldInfo != null);
                }
            }

            t = t.BaseType;
        } while (t != null);

        return new Delegate[] { };
    }
}
```

Finally, though I made some pretty big modifications to the code, I have to give [credit to Bob Powell](https://web.archive.org/web/20131213074318/http://bobpowell.net/eventsubscribers.aspx) for getting me started on this.

Comment: Seems to be what I am looking for ^^ Let's see if it works :P

Comment: Hmm I don't know how to use it one the static event oO Do I have to edit the external dll, I mean do I have to add this to the class that implements the event ?

Comment: @lorenzalbert: You shouldn't have to, it's a `public virtual` method.

Comment: Hmm maybe you can help me with the given example code in my edit. I understood everything but accessing the list of delegates with `getInvocationList`. I mean you added the event CheckInvocationList if i do this I can access the delegates but I dont know how to concetenate everything so that it works.

Comment: Edit your question and post the code you have at this very moment (that's calling GetInvocationList) and I'll try and help.

Comment: Hmm that's my problem I want to call `GetInvocationList` on `HookManager.KeyUp` but atm I don't know how to do it (there is nothing I can do but adding/removing delegates to the event). Otherwise I would be completely fine.

Comment: @lorenzalbert: I think I've got a solution for you, please take a look at the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Ok, it almost works but I have 2 problems. First I have VS 2008 hence dynamic is not available. I did some changes but it is bugged if I add different events to an object I get an exception `The non static field requires a target`. Check my edit for the code. And the 2nd problem is that `Hookmanager` is static but the functions requires and object.

Comment: @lorenzalbert: do you have the code for `HookManager`? I really need that to continue this. It will allow me to duplicate it.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C i am using version 2

Answer (score 1):

I believe that simply comparing HookManager.KeyUp to null will give you your answer.

Other than that, though, unless things have changed since last I looked into it (quite possible) it's rather difficult to get an actual list of the delegates associated with an event.  But if the value is null, that tells you that no delegates are associated with it.

Comment: just an FYI, I have added an example that shows how to get the invocation list of an event.